# Update an object in a nested array with $set and $[identifier] (mongoDB 3.6)

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 3.6 allow to perform complex array manipulations against all matching elements in any array – no matter how deeply nested – [Update Nested Arrays with $[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

Consider the document below on `survey` collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5a7d86d8fac139e71b0b9f5b",
    "results": [
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "comments": [
              {
                "id" : "123456",
                "email": "user@email.com",
                "content": "comment 1",
                "createdAt": "2018-05-03"
                "replies": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm trying to update the comment `email`, `content` and `createdAt` fields and without touching to the `id` and `replies` fields.

I'm using `$set` and the new `$[<identifier>]`

I tried the `command` below based on [The update command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) :

```
db.runCommand({
  update: "survey",
  updates: [
    {
      q: {},
      u: {
        $set: {
          "results.$[].items.$[].comments.$[comment]": {
            "email": "user2@email.com",
            "content": "comment 2",
            "createdAt": "2018-05-04"
          }
        }
      },
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "comment.id": { 
            $eq: "123456"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

The command works but it removes the `id` and `replies` fields.

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$set` with document `{}` overwrites the matching document. Use `$set` and list all the document fields using dot notation to perform field level updates. More [`here`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array).

```
db.runCommand({
  update: "survey",
  updates: [
    {
      q: {},
      u: {
        $set: {
          "results.$[].items.$[].comments.$[comment].email": "user2@email.com",
          "results.$[].items.$[].comments.$[comment].content": "comment 2",
          "results.$[].items.$[].comments.$[comment].createdAt": "2018-05-04"
        }
      },
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "comment.id": { 
            $eq: "123456"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: This is an alternative, but in case when we have a lot of fields to update, it will be difficult to list them all like this.

Comment: Its either replace or you list them all. You can read all the fields from database and do a merge on client side and send the whole doc.